# haproxy starts empty (without tcp service section)

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, haproxy-ingress

we use haproxy-ingress v0.13.6 (HA-Proxy version 2.3.17-d1c9119 2022/01/11) (and the previous haproxy-ingress versions performed the same) on k8s 1.19
and from time to time we have a problem when haproxy pod restarts due to liveness, node, or other reasons, it starts without the servers section
in that case the lines listed below are not appearing inside /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg file

```
  # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# #
# #   TCP SERVICES (legacy, via configmap)
# #
#
listen _tcp_namespace_project-haproxy-stats_111
    bind :111
    mode tcp
    log-format "[%t] %ci:%cp %si:%sp %bi:%bp %fi:%fp %ft %b/%s %Tw/%Tc/%Tt %B %ts %ac/%fc/%bc/%sc/%rc %sq/%bq"

    option log-health-checks
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check send "AAA"
    tcp-check expect string "BBB"

    # Recognized options podMaxConn: 2
    default-server check port 111 inter 2s maxconn 2 observe layer4 error-limit 1 on-error mark-down
    server-template project-worker.namespace- 3 project-worker.namespace.svc.cluster.local:111 resolvers kubernetes resolve-prefer ipv4 init-addr none
```

I'm able to reproduce that problem by manually issuing 'reboot' command using k8s exec, that needs several attempts.

k8s rollout restart deployment resolves that problem
else patching tcp-service configmap helps, if I'm modifying, appending, or deleting some lines in the configmap, haproxy reloads the config and starts working according to the configmap content
reload manually with /haproxy-reload.sh doesn't help

Another difference between working and not working correctly instances

```
/ # ps axjf | more
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
...
   34 root      0:00 haproxy -f /etc/haproxy -p /var/run/haproxy/haproxy.pid -D -sf
...
```

and that's from the healthy one

```
/ # ps axjf | more
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
...
   43 root      0:00 haproxy -f /etc/haproxy -p /var/run/haproxy/haproxy.pid -D -sf 31 -x
...
```

Comment: There is no `haproxy v0.13.6` the official HAProxy version can be found in the table on this page https://www.haproxy.org/ . Please explain your setup a little bit more

Comment: you're right that's haproxy-ingress version - updated the description